# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'dialog' of 'require(...).remote' as it is undefined even thought enable remote modules set to true

Tags: javascript, electron

I am trying to open a dialog box in my electron app but when I Try importing it in my app.js the error in the title shows up even thought 'enableRemoteModule' is set to true .

I am trying to open a dialog box in my electron app but when I Try importing it in my app.js the error in the title shows up even thought 'enableRemoteModule' is set to true .

app.js

```
const { dialog } = require("electron").remote;

    const OpenBookBtn = document.getElementById("OpenBookBtn")
    const viewerElement = document.getElementById('viewer')
    const CloseBookBtn = document.getElementById("CloseBookBtn")
    
    
    WebViewer({
        path:'../public/lib',
    },viewerElement).then(instance =>{
        instance.setTheme("dark");
    })
    
    
    viewerElement.style.display = 'none'
    
    OpenBookBtn.addEventListener('click',()=>{
        const file = dialog.showOpenDialog();
        viewerElement.style.display = "block"
    })
    
    CloseBookBtn.addEventListener('click',(event)=>{
        viewerElement.style.display = 'none'
    })
```

index.js

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron');
const path = require('path');

// Handle creating/removing shortcuts on Windows when installing/uninstalling.
if (require('electron-squirrel-startup')) { // eslint-disable-line global-require
  app.quit();
}

const createWindow = () => {
  // Create the browser window.
  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
      webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
      enableRemoteModule: true,
      contextIsolation: false,
    },
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
  });

  // and load the index.html of the app.
  mainWindow.loadFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'));

  // Open the DevTools.
  mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
};

// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
// Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.
app.on('ready', createWindow);

// Quit when all windows are closed, except on macOS. There, it's common
// for applications and their menu bar to stay active until the user quits
// explicitly with Cmd + Q.
app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit();
  }
});

app.on('activate', () => {
  // On OS X it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
  // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
  if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
    createWindow();
  }
});

// In this file you can include the rest of your app's specific main process
// code. You can also put them in separate files and import them here.
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First install the remote module using

```
> npm install @electron/remote
```

In the new versions of electron, you have to include remote as

```
const remote = require('@electron/remote');
const { dialog } = remote;
```

And in your index.js file add the following

```
const remoteMain = require('@electron/remote/main');
remoteMain.initialize();
```

Also, after creating the mainWindow object

```
remoteMain.enable(mainWindow.webContents)
```